# type error in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I am getting the following error:

```
exercise-2-2.hs:15:49:
    Couldn't match expected type `Double' with actual type `Int'
    In the fourth argument of `regularPolygonHelper', namely `theta'
    In the expression: regularPolygonHelper n s 0 theta r
    In an equation for `regularPolygon':
        regularPolygon n s
          = regularPolygonHelper n s 0 theta r
          where
              r = s / 2.0 * (sin (pi / n))
              theta = (2.0 * pi) / n
```

in the following code:

```
data Shape = Rectangle Side Side
           | Ellipse Radius Radius
           | RTTriangle Side Side
           | Polygon [Vertex]
    deriving Show

type Radius = Float
type Side   = Float
type Vertex = (Float, Float)

square s = Rectangle s s
circle r = Ellipse r r

regularPolygon :: Int -> Side -> Shape
regularPolygon n s = regularPolygonHelper n s 0 theta r
    where r     = s / 2.0 * (sin (pi / n))
          theta = (2.0 * pi) / n

regularPolygonHelper :: Int -> Side -> Int -> Double -> Double -> Shape
regularPolygonHelper 0 s i theta r = Polygon []
regularPolygonHelper n s i theta r = 
    (r * cos (i * theta), r * sin (i * theta)) : 
        (regularPolygonHelper (n - 1) s (i + 1) theta r)
```

Why is this?  Isn't `(2.0 * pi) / n` a double?

Comment: please note the Problem with your last call in regularPolygonHelper - your are prepending a Vertex onto a Shape - but you want to prepend a vertex to a Vertex-list and return "Polygon newList"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haskell has no automatic conversion between different numeric types. You have to do this by hand. In your case, `(2.0 * pi) / fromIntegral n` would do the trick. (You have to add this at all the other places where you want to have a cast too) The reason for this is, that implicit conversion would make type inference much harder, IMHO it is better to have type inference than automatic conversion.

Comment: strange - tried this but it's not the only problem and in my case didn't work as well ... but if it's the correct answer ... ok

Comment: Automatic conversion can also lead to loss of precision, which can be another possible headache to track down. Overall, I think explicit is better than implicit when it comes to mixing numeric types.

Comment: did you guys check the code with the propoed changes? does it work and does it produce the right outputs (for example a simple square)?

Comment: there is still the problem with regularPolygonHelper as far as I can tell

Comment: @CKoenig *You have to add this at all the other places where you want to have a cast too* ... Did you actually read my answer?

Comment: @FUZxxl: yes I did and yes I changed all places - but with orginal-code you will see the following problem "Couldn't match expected type `[(Double, Double)]'
           against inferred type `Shape'
..."

Comment: Sorry for being rude. The reason for this is, that you accumulate a list of vertices. In the first case, you return a real Shape while you return a list of vertices in the second case. I suggest to change the return type to [Vertex] and to add the wrapper at another place.

Answer (score 2):

better not mix the types so much
here is a version that compiles so far:

```
data Shape = Rectangle Side Side
           | Ellipse Radius Radius
           | RTTriangle Side Side
           | Polygon [Vertex]
    deriving Show

type Radius = Double
type Side   = Double
type Vertex = (Double, Double)

square s = Rectangle s s
circle r = Ellipse r r

regularPolygon :: Int -> Side -> Shape
regularPolygon n s = regularPolygonHelper n s 0 theta r
    where r     = s / 2.0 * (sin (pi / fromIntegral n))
          theta = (2.0 * pi) / fromIntegral n

regularPolygonHelper :: Int -> Side -> Int -> Double -> Double -> Shape
regularPolygonHelper 0 s i theta r = Polygon []
regularPolygonHelper n s i theta r = 
    let Polygon rPoly = regularPolygonHelper (n - 1) s (i + 1) theta r in
    Polygon ((r * cos (fromIntegral i * theta), r * sin (fromIntegral i * theta)) : rPoly)
```

Comment: the output of this don't look correct to me - but I don't think the problem is with my changes ... not sure though but I'm tired ... sorry

Comment: I would not use `Double` for the number of sides. It leaves the door open to errors like passing `0.5` which would cause the `0` base case to be skipped. On a similar note, I'd probably add an `error` case for negative numbers.

Comment: true - just a quick hack anyway, as I don't think the algorithm works correct. But as I mentioned: does the fromIntegral solve the trick? I don't think so. don't you need some kind of Int -> Double(Float)? I'm a bit ashamed but I don't know how to do this in haskell :(

Comment: Look at the type of `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`. It can convert from any integral type (e.g. `Int`), to any numeric type (e.g. `Double`).

Comment: well after reading a bit it should be fromIntegral - but why did my GHCi throw on me ... well I must be really sleepy .. sorry will work on it tomorrow ...

Comment: ok - right ... must have been another error (on my side) ... will edit the code -thanks a lot

Comment: the algorithm might even work this way ... look ok to me (regularPolygon for n=3,4,5)